# A geometry problem involving geometric mean

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a quadrilateral inscribed in a circle of center $O$. Let $BD$ bisect $OC$ perpendicularly. $P$ is a point on the diagonal $AC$ such that $PC=OC$. $BP$ cuts $AD$ at $E$ and the circle circumscribing $ABCD$ at $F$.

[image: Figure]

Prove that $PF$ is the geometric mean of $EF$ and $BF$.

Comment: Can you draw a picture? This is not very clear and when trying to draw it, I found myself with $B=F$, since the circle circumscribing $ABCD$ is the circle of center $O$...

Comment: i drew the picture but did not get B=F i could not put the picture here because i donot know how to draw here

Comment: When you edit a post, there is a button with a picture on it. You can use that to upload an image file.

Comment: You seem to assume that the circle with center $C$ and radius $CO$ passes through $B$ and $D$, but this fact does not follow from the hypothesis.

Comment: @Jack: Doesn't that follow from the fact that $BD$ bisects $OC$ perpendicularly? So $OM=MC$ and $OC\perp BD$ so $B$ and $D$ lie on the symmetry axis between the two circles and are therefore common points.

Comment: @MvG: ok, you are right, I missed the "bisects" part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction, points $O$, $B$, $D$, $P$ lie on $\bigcirc C$, and $\stackrel{\frown}{BCD} = \stackrel{\frown}{BOD} = 120^\circ$.

[image]

Note that $\angle DBF \cong DCF$ (marked "$\theta$") as inscribed angles of $\bigcirc O$ subtending $\stackrel{\frown}{DF}$. Likewise, $\angle ACF\cong \angle ADF$ (marked "$\phi$").

Further, since $\angle BFD$ subtends $\stackrel{\frown}{BCD}$ of $\bigcirc O$, and since $\angle BPD$ subtends major arc $\stackrel{\frown}{BD}$ of $\bigcirc C$, we have

$$\angle BFD = \frac{1}{2}\stackrel{\frown}{BCD} =60^\circ$$
$$\angle DPF = 180^\circ - \angle DPB = 180^\circ - \frac{1}{2}\left(360^\circ-\stackrel{\frown}{BOD}\right) = 60^\circ$$
This implies that $\triangle PDF$ is equilateral. Moreover, $\square PCDF$ is a kite, with diagonal $\overline{CF}$ bisecting $\angle C$, so that $\theta = \phi$.

Consequently, $\triangle FDE \sim \triangle FBD$, whereupon
$$\frac{|\overline{EF}|}{|\overline{DF}|} = \frac{|\overline{DF}|}{|\overline{BF}|}\qquad\to\qquad |\overline{DF}|^2 = |\overline{BF}||\overline{EF}|$$

Since $\overline{DF}\cong\overline{PF}$ in equilateral $\triangle PDF$, we have our result. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

This is a coordinate-based solution. Without loss of generality, you can choose your coordinate system such that the circle $\bigcirc ABCD$ becomes the unit circle and $C$ has coordinates $(1,0)$. Then, in order to simplify the formulation, we start by choosing rational coordinates for point $P$:

$$P = (2t^2,2t)/(t^2+1)$$

The coordinates are chosen in such a way that they describe any point on the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ except for the point $(2,0)$ (which corresponds to $t\to\infty$). For any point $P$ on that circle you can compute $t=y/(2-x)$.

From these coordinates, everything else can be computed:

\begin{align*}
O&=(0,0) \\
C&=(1,0) \\
\bigcirc ABCD&:\;\;x^2+y^2=1 \\
\bigcirc OBD&:\;\;(x-1)^2+y^2=1 \\
B&=(1,-\sqrt3)/2 \\
D&=(1,\sqrt3)/2 \\
P&=(2t^2,2t)/(t^2+1) \\
CP&:\;\;2t\,x+(1-t^2)\,y=2t \\
BP&:\;\;(t+\sqrt3)\,x+(1-\sqrt3t)\,y=2t \\
A&=(-t^4 + 6t^2 - 1, -4t^3 + 4t)/(t^4 + 2t^2 + 1) \\
AD&:\;\;(1-t^2-2\sqrt3t)\,x+(\sqrt3t^2 - 2t - \sqrt3)y = t^2 - 2\sqrt3t - 1 \\
E&=(-3\sqrt3t^3 + 11t^2 + \sqrt3t - 1, -3t^3 - 3\sqrt3t^2 + 9t + \sqrt3)/(4t^2 + 4) \\
F&=(t^2 + 2\sqrt3t - 1, -\sqrt3t^2 + 2t + \sqrt3)/(2t^2 + 2) \\
\lVert P-F\rVert^2&=(3t^2 - 2\sqrt3t + 1)/(t^2 + 1) \\
\lVert E-F\rVert^2&=(9t^4 - 12\sqrt3t^3 + 18t^2 - 4\sqrt3t + 1)/(4t^2 + 4) \\
\lVert B-F\rVert^2&=4/(t^2 + 1) \\
\lVert P-F\rVert^4 &= \lVert E-F\rVert^2\cdot\lVert B-F\rVert^2
= (\sqrt3t - 1)^4/(t^2+1)^2
\end{align*}

I did all the computation using projective geometry and homogeneous coordinates. So the things I write as $(x,y)/z$ were internally just homogeneous coordinate vectors $(x,y,z)$ in my computation. And of course I used a computer algebra system (sage in this case) to handle all these polynomials.